# layout_gravity="bottom" not working

Tags: android

In my android layout, I have two EditText elements. They appear side by side at the bottom of the screen. But when i type multiple lines into the first EditText(on the left), the second one(at the right) also keeps moving upwards even though it is empty. I have specified `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` and `android:gravity="bottom"` for the second EditText. But it has no effect. What am i doing wrong? How can i make the second EditText stay at the vertical center of its parent linear layout, no matter how many lines are entered in the first EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textinput"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_input1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using android:gravity="center" for the linearlayout did work. But the line of the second EditText still stays at the bottom, even though the text entry happens at the center. I am facing this same issue with the other solution provided here. I am beginning to think that is the designed behaviour of an EditText element.

Comment: oh wait it worked! I had changed the layout_height of the second EditText to "match_parent" while experimenting. It worked after i changed it back to "wrap_content". Thanks!

Comment: Misleading answer. `layout_width` and `layout_weight` have no relation.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using android:layout_height="match_parent" in my Linear layout caused the screen to be filled with my linear layout. So i used it only in my second EditText instead and it worked partially i.e. the EditText does not move upwards anymore. But now it is stuck at the bottom. Even if i change the gravity and layout_gravity to center, the EditText "line" stays at at the bottom, while the text entry happens at the center. how do i keep the line always at the vertical center?

Comment: The behaviour is same after removing it. i.e. the text entry happens at the center, but the line is stuck at the bottom.

Comment: It worked after using android:gravity="center" for the linearlayout as suggested by another answer. Thanks.